# How can I fix a 'List<dynamic> is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' error in Flutter HTTP?

Tags: flutter, http

I'm getting "_TypeError (type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>')" error on flutter.

I am trying to parse a string url for taking http.post but I'm getting "_TypeError (type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>')" error on flutter.

```
  void editData() {
    var url = "http://192.168.1.85/dashboard/myFolder/editdata.php";
    http.post(Uri.parse(url), body: {
      'id': widget.list[widget.index],
      'name': cname.text,
      'mobile': cmobile.text,
    });
  }
```

the error occurs in the http.post seciton of the code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Take a look at Flutter docs: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/send-data.